# Find area of a parallelogram with vertex at the origin and with the given vectors as edges

Tags: determinant, area

Find area of a parallelogram with vertex at the origin and with the given vectors as edges: $i +3j - 5k$ and $i +7j - k.$

So matrixes for me take the longest time to put in LaTeX so im just asking if im logic for this is right.

I would let the first vector be b, and the 2nd vector be c. Then I would compute

$\| b \times c \|.$

Is that right?

Comment: Your logic is correct.

Comment: You can also consider the plane passing trough the origin and your points. In that plane consider your vectors as canonic ones and compute the determinant of the matrix